# GNU make show only error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to configure GNU make to only show error. `make --no-print-directory` suppresses all the Entering/Leaving messages. similarly I don't want to see "`make[4]: Nothing to be done for install.`". Just the build error.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make -s` won't print any of the commands (as if every command was prefixed by `@`). If the commands themselves are printing output, try redirecting standard output away but keeping standard error.

```
make -s >/dev/null
```

However my recommendation would be to let all the output through, because it can be very useful to figure out what's going on. Use a tool such as [colormake](http://bre.klaki.net/programs/colormake/) to make it more readable.